# Distance Types for Hierarchical Clustering in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, hierarchical-clustering

I want to use the hierarchicalClustering function of the flann module of OpenCV 3.0. The data I want to cluster are descriptors of ORB features, so it would be reasonable to use the *Hamming distance*. But this does not work with OpenCV.

Is there any better solution than using the L2 distance?

This is the code I use:

```
cvflann::KMeansIndexParams params(32, 11, vflann::FLANN_CENTERS_KMEANSPP);
true_no_words = flann::hierarchicalClustering<cvflann::L2<unsigned char>>(in_words,out_temp,params);
```

I want to do something like:

```
cvflann::KMeansIndexParams params(32, 11, vflann::FLANN_CENTERS_KMEANSPP);
true_no_words = flann::hierarchicalClustering<cvflann::Hamming>(in_words,out_temp,params);
```

Comment: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/6355